# c# regex interpolated quantifying

Tags: c#, regex

i have trobles with regex:
i have pattern:

```
string pattern = $"^[0-9]+([A-Za-z]{variable})[^a-z]*$";
```

i read "variable" from console like

```
int variable=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Ok - what's your actual problem?

Comment: I think you need `$"^[0-9]+([A-Za-z]{{{variable}}})[^a-z]*$"`

Comment: I want to read quantifire limit for [A-Za-z]{limit}  from another variable..

Comment: YES, thank you Wiktor! Works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to use a [limiting quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) minimum threshold value as a dynamic one, you need to add *literal* `{` and `}` to the interpolated string literal.

In interpolated string literals, `{` and `}` define the interpolated part where you may use code, and to make them literal, you need to double them.

Use

```
var pattern = $"^[0-9]+([A-Za-z]{{{variable}}})[^a-z]*$";
```